# Creating a hierarchy with functional programming in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming

Say I have an array like this:

```
[
  { id: 1, parent: null },
  { id: 2, parent: null },
  { id: 3, parent: 2 },
  ...
]
```

This hierarchy can nest deeply. How can I create a multidimensional array/object out of this one dimensional array with **functional programming** in JavaScript? (Say with LoDash.)

**EDIT**: Sorry, if anyone thinks this question lacks specification like an output format. I tried to stay generic with this question on purpose!

Comment: And where is the code you've already tried?

Comment: How would you want to represent your hierarchy with a "multidimensional array"? Or do you mean a "tree"? Please show the expected output format.

Comment: Also, JS doesn't really do MD arrays.

Comment: I have no code show-worthy code I tried which wouldn't be more confusing than helpful. I don't really care about the representation, thats why I didn't specify it any further. This is a more generic question. And why can't JS do multidimensional array? Isn't this a 2-dimensional array: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
a = [
    { id: 1, parent: null },
    { id: 2, parent: null },
    { id: 3, parent: 2 },
    { id: 4, parent: 2 },
    { id: 5, parent: 4 },
    { id: 6, parent: 3 },
    { id: 7, parent: 1 }
]

tree = function(node) {
    node.children = a.filter(function(x) { return x.parent == node.id }).map(tree);
    return node;
}

t = tree({parent:null})
console.log(JSON.stringify(t,null,3))
```

Result

```
{
   "parent": null,
   "children": [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "parent": null,
         "children": [
            {
               "id": 7,
               "parent": 1,
               "children": []
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id": 2,
         "parent": null,
         "children": [
            {
               "id": 3,
               "parent": 2,
               "children": [
                  {
                     "id": 6,
                     "parent": 3,
                     "children": []
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "id": 4,
               "parent": 2,
               "children": [
                  {
                     "id": 5,
                     "parent": 4,
                     "children": []
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Wow, that looks so simple. That was exactly the purpose of the question. Thank you.